# Cosmos DB entity not found on delete but exists and able to get

Tags: typescript, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Whenever I try to delete an Item using it's id, I get an entity not found error, but the Item exists in the DB and I'm also able to retrieve it using the SQL format.

I'm not understanding where am I wrong in the code but whenever I retrieve an item with it's ID I'm able to find it, whenever I try to delete it it fails.

This is my code to get:

```
async getAsset(assetId: string): Promise<Asset> {
    const assetsDb = await getDbClient(cosmoDBContainers.assets);
    const response = await assetsDb.items
      .query<Asset>({
        query: `SELECT * FROM ${cosmoDBContainers.assets} A 
                WHERE A.id = @id`,
        parameters: [{ name: "@id", value: assetId }],
      }).fetchAll();
    return response.resources.map(x => new Asset(
      x.id,
      x.orgId,
      x.assetType,
      x.title,
      x.createdAt,
      x.lastUpdate,
      x.fileStorageId,
    ))[0];
} // item successfully retrieved
```

This is the code to delete (note I'm calling the getAsset function):

```
async removeAsset(assetId: string): Promise<void> {
    const assetsDb = await getDbClient(cosmoDBContainers.assets);

    const asset = await this.getAsset(assetId); // calling this in order to check that the Ids are the same, which they are
    const item = assetsDb.item(asset.Id); // this line seems to work
    await item.delete(); // error is thrown here
  }
```

The partition key in CosmosDB is "/id", I've tried adding it when calling `assetsDb.item(asset.Id, "/id")` but I still get the same not found error.

This is the full error

```
 Error: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.
```

I've tried a few things from other answers in SO but nothing seems to be working, I suspect it might be an issue on my side, but I'm completely lost at this point, any idea would be super helpful.

I'm using TypeScript and  `"@azure/cosmos": "^3.11.0"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the following lines of code:

```
const item = assetsDb.item(asset.Id);
await item.delete();
```

to

```
const item = assetsDb.item(asset.Id, asset.Id);//assuming your partition key value is same as document id.
await item.delete();
```

And your delete operation should work.

Essentially there are two issues:

1. In the following code `const item = assetsDb.item(asset.Id);`, you're not specifying the partition key value of the document. In this case, SDK made use of default partition key value. Since there's no document in that default partition with the matching id, you get item not found error.
2. When you tried this code `assetsDb.item(asset.Id, "/id")`, you actually need to specify the partition key value instead of partition key attribute name. Since you're specifying "/id" for the partition key value, Cosmos DB looked for an item with matching id in "/id" logical partition. Again, since there is no valid combination found, you got the error.

By using `const item = assetsDb.item(asset.Id, asset.Id);`, you're telling Azure Cosmos DB about both the item's id and its partition key value.

Comment: I fully misinterpreted the documentation. I thought that the "value" of the partition key was it's name (so to speak), which we can see in the azure portal. I've tried the way you said and works like charm. Thank you :)

Comment: You're not alone :). Even I have made the same mistake in the past.